# Flag column based on min(date) of different rows each 2 months

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

I got a table like this that has info of different complaints

```
telephone   motive  complaint_id    complaint_date
980761524   motive1 R1234561        23/05/2017
980761524   motive1 R1234562        23/05/2017
980761524   motive1 R1234563        25/08/2017
980761524   motive1 R1234564        26/09/2017
980761524   motive1 R1234565        10/10/2017
980761524   motive1 R1234566        30/12/2017
991761525   motive2 R4454222        24/06/2017
991761525   motive2 R4454223        29/06/2017
991761525   motive2 R4454224        30/10/2017
940789563   motive3 R8993271        24/06/2017
940789563   motive3 R8993272        29/06/2017
940789563   motive3 R8993273        30/10/2017
```

I need to write a query (oracle-sql) that marks with a repeat_flag(new column) for the the complaint(s) that have the same telephone, the same motive with the min(complaint_date) as 0 but this min(complaint_date) changes each 2 monhts.

Let me explain in detail.

So let's say I'm analyzing the first group of telephone/motive which is

```
telephone  motive  complaint_id    complaint_date
980761524   motive1 R1234561        23/05/2017
980761524   motive1 R1234562        23/05/2017
980761524   motive1 R1234563        25/08/2017
980761524   motive1 R1234564        26/09/2017
980761524   motive1 R1234565        10/10/2017
980761524   motive1 R1234566        30/12/2017
```

The min(complaint_date)of this group is `23/05/2017`, 2 rows has the same date here. So to leave only one, I go to column complaint_id to see the first complaint that was generated. All complaints_id are `R+Number` and the lowest number is the first complaint(R1234561) and mark it as `0`. So if the date of the next row is 2months within the first min(complaint_date) I mark it as 1.

If the next complaint_date is within two months then you have a repeat complaint and you mark it as 1.  In this example, `23/05/2017` is within so I mark it a 1.

If the next complaint_date is not within two months then is not a repeat and you mark it as '0'. Now the complaint_date here is `25/08/2017` and now this the new *min(complaint_date)*

Next row, here I got `26/09/2017` which is within 2 months `25/08/2017` so this is a repeat and I mark it as 1.

Next row, here I got `10/10/2017` which is within 2 months `25/08/2017` so this is a repeat and I mark it as 1.

Finally, here I got `30/12/2017` which is not within 2 months `25/08/2017` so this is not  repeat and I mark it as . and now this the new *min(complaint_date)*

Same for further rows.

The final result should look like this

```
telephone   motive  complaint   complaint_date  2months_repeat_flag
980761524   motive1 R1234561        23/05/2017                   0
980761524   motive1 R1234562        23/05/2017                   1
980761524   motive1 R1234563        25/08/2017                   0
980761524   motive1 R1234563        26/09/2017                   1
980761524   motive1 R1234563        10/10/2017                   1
980761524   motive1 R1234563        30/12/2017                   0
```

And the final table should look like this

```
telephone   motive  complaint   complaint_date  2months_repeat_flag
980761524   motive1 R1234561        23/05/2017                    0
980761524   motive1 R1234562        23/05/2017                    1
980761524   motive1 R1234563        25/08/2017                    0
980761524   motive1 R1234564        26/09/2017                    1
980761524   motive1 R1234565        10/10/2017                    1
980761524   motive1 R1234566        30/12/2017                    0
991761525   motive2 R4454222        24/06/2017                    0
991761525   motive2 R4454223        29/06/2017                    1
991761525   motive2 R4454224        30/10/2017                    0
940789563   motive3 R8993271        24/06/2017                    0
940789563   motive3 R8993272        29/06/2017                    1
940789563   motive3 R8993273        30/10/2017                    0
```

My table has around 2 to 30 complaints with the same telephone and the same motive.

Is it possible with just SQL? Any stored procedure is welcomed. But I prefer to do this with just SQL because my user has no rights for creating sp's.

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to stack overflow!  Could you please provide some sample data?  It's good to see the explanation of your issue here as well as what you need, but it's very helpful to also provide sample insert statements so that others can easily recreate some dummy data to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution that should work in Oracle 10 and above. It uses the `model` clause (the distant ancestor of the `match_recognize` clause). `match_recognize`, available in Oracle 12 and above, is probably a few times faster, but may not work for the OP (question is tagged `oracle11g`).

**Setup**:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy';

create table test_data ( telephone, motive, complaint_id, complaint_date ) as
    select 980761524, 'motive1', 'R1234561', to_date('23/05/2017') from dual union all
    select 980761524, 'motive1', 'R1234562', to_date('23/05/2017') from dual union all
    select 980761524, 'motive1', 'R1234563', to_date('25/08/2017') from dual union all
    select 980761524, 'motive1', 'R1234564', to_date('26/09/2017') from dual union all
    select 980761524, 'motive1', 'R1234565', to_date('10/10/2017') from dual union all
    select 980761524, 'motive1', 'R1234566', to_date('30/12/2017') from dual union all
    select 991761525, 'motive2', 'R4454222', to_date('24/06/2017') from dual union all
    select 991761525, 'motive2', 'R4454223', to_date('29/06/2017') from dual union all
    select 991761525, 'motive2', 'R4454224', to_date('30/10/2017') from dual union all
    select 940789563, 'motive3', 'R8993271', to_date('24/06/2017') from dual union all
    select 940789563, 'motive3', 'R8993272', to_date('29/06/2017') from dual union all
    select 940789563, 'motive3', 'R8993273', to_date('30/10/2017') from dual
;

commit;
```

**Query**:

```
select telephone, motive, complaint_id, complaint_date, flag
from   test_data
model  
  partition by (telephone, motive)  
  dimension by (row_number() over (partition by telephone, motive 
                                   order by     complaint_date, complaint_id) rn)
  measures (complaint_id, complaint_date, complaint_date s, 0 flag)  
  rules (  
    s[rn>1]    = case when complaint_date[cv(rn)] < add_months(s[cv(rn) - 1], 2)  
                      then s[cv(rn) - 1]  
                      else complaint_date[cv(rn)]  
                 end,
    flag[rn>1] = case when s[cv(rn)] = s[cv(rn) - 1] then 1 else 0 end
  )
order by telephone, motive, rn
;
```

**Output**: (ordered by telephone, then by motive - that can be changed as needed)

```
 TELEPHONE   MOTIVE    COMPLAINT_ID COMPLAINT_DATE FLAG
 ---------   -------   ------------ -------------- ----
 940789563   motive3   R8993271     24/06/2017        0
 940789563   motive3   R8993272     29/06/2017        1
 940789563   motive3   R8993273     30/10/2017        0
 980761524   motive1   R1234561     23/05/2017        0
 980761524   motive1   R1234562     23/05/2017        1
 980761524   motive1   R1234563     25/08/2017        0
 980761524   motive1   R1234564     26/09/2017        1
 980761524   motive1   R1234565     10/10/2017        1
 980761524   motive1   R1234566     30/12/2017        0
 991761525   motive2   R4454222     24/06/2017        0
 991761525   motive2   R4454223     29/06/2017        1
 991761525   motive2   R4454224     30/10/2017        0
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked perfectly. Do you mind sharing the oracle12 one?

Comment: @gabuglc - I just posted the Oracle 12 solution in a separate answer (because it is, indeed, a different answer). You should test the different solutions to see which is the most efficient. Experience suggests that, if Oracle 12 is available, `match_recognize` will have a significant advantage, but the best way to know for sure is to test.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is based on recursive `CONNECT BY` clause

```
SELECT t.*,
       CASE WHEN t1.complaint_id IS NULL
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 
       END As two_months_repeat_flag
FROM test_data t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT complaint_id
    FROM (
        select t.complaint_id,
               (
                 SELECT min( complaint_id ) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY complaint_date, complaint_id )
                 FROM test_data t1
                 WHERE t1.telephone = t.telephone
                   AND t1.motive = t.motive 
                   AND t1.complaint_date > add_months( t.complaint_date, 2 )
               ) as next_complaint_id,
               row_number() over (partition by telephone, motive order BY complaint_date, complaint_id) as rn
        from test_data t
    )
    start with rn = 1
    connect by complaint_id = prior next_complaint_id
) t1
ON t.complaint_id = t1.complaint_id
ORDER BY 1, 2,4,3
```

---

```
 TELEPHONE MOTIVE  COMPLAIN COMPLAINT_ TWO_MONTHS_REPEAT_FLAG
---------- ------- -------- ---------- ----------------------
 940789563 motive3 R8993271 24/06/2017                      0
 940789563 motive3 R8993272 29/06/2017                      1
 940789563 motive3 R8993273 30/10/2017                      0
 980761524 motive1 R1234561 23/05/2017                      0
 980761524 motive1 R1234562 23/05/2017                      1
 980761524 motive1 R1234563 25/08/2017                      0
 980761524 motive1 R1234564 26/09/2017                      1
 980761524 motive1 R1234565 10/10/2017                      1
 980761524 motive1 R1234566 30/12/2017                      0
 991761525 motive2 R4454222 24/06/2017                      0
 991761525 motive2 R4454223 29/06/2017                      1
 991761525 motive2 R4454224 30/10/2017                      0

12 rows selected.
```

Comment: This will work, but it will probably be very slow (due to the need for the correlated subquery in the innermost part of the code). In 11.2 and above, a recursive CTE can be written that will avoid most of the unneeded work, but it will likely still be slower than the `model` approach. Regardless, +1 for a correct approach and solution.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the Oracle's LAG function which let's you access value from the previous row:

```
 SELECT telephone,
        motive,
        complaint_id,
        complaint_date,
        CASE WHEN 
           ADD_MONTHS(LAG  (complaint_date, 1 , NULL) 
                        OVER (PARTITION BY  telephone, motive 
                              ORDER BY complaint_date),2) > complaint_date   
             THEN 1 ELSE 0  END AS flag
   FROM test_data
```

This solution assumes you want the difference since the last complaint - not the first complaint.

Comment: The detailed examples the OP gave show that the assumption is wrong. Did you read the OP's question?

Comment: Hello, Can you workaround this LAG function to match the difference with the first complaint? This would be useful. Thank you

Comment: @gabuglc - that is not possible, unfortunately. Analytic functions alone cannot solve the problem as you posed it.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle 12.1 and above, here is a solution that uses the `match_recognize` clause. The OP should try the various solutions (the ones that solve the problem as proposed, anyway) to see which is the most efficient for his/her specific data.

```
select telephone, motive, complaint_id, complaint_date,
       case classif when 'A' then 0 else 1 end
from   test_data
match_recognize (
  partition by telephone, motive
  order by complaint_date, complaint_id
  measures classifier() as classif
  all rows per match
  pattern ( a x* )
  define  x as complaint_date <= add_months(a.complaint_date, 2)
)
order by telephone, motive, complaint_date, complaint_id
;
```